# How to output a field as a link in D7

Tags: navigation

On the user/edit pages I would like to display a link based on a (text?)'field' 
The link should only be displayed to users with the proper permission.
For this, I'll use the [Field Permissions](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module.

My problem is that I don't to know how to output the field as a link.

I have tried the [Link](https://drupal.org/project/link) module but this seems to give users the ability to input a link.

In my case users should only see the link on their account page.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you are using field permissions to stop users from viewing this you can also use field permissions to stop users from editing it and just use the link module. How are you stopping them from inputting into the text field?

Comment: The text field was more of a suggestion. As i thought this field should be used. I have tried the link module again. However it seems that users should have edit permissions to see the field. Again to me this looks for input purposes only. Once the content is saved it becomes a link. In my case the field should be a link before saving the content.

Comment: The link is for viewing purposes only.
It should link to 'terms of use'. After submission the link should be hidden by permission.

Comment: To be more specific: a default value should put in by the webadmin..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it sounds like you aren't trying to add a field, but rather, are trying to DISPLAY a field (link, more specifically) on the user account page.

What you need to do is simply edit the user profile template of your theme to show the link you need in the footer/header or wherever else you need.

Something like the below should work:

- Go into our drupal root folder and from /modules/user/ copy the **user-profile.tpl.php** file and paste it into your theme's /templates folder
- It should just have code that looks like this to begin with:

> ```
> <div class="profile"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
>    <?php print render($user_profile); ?>
> </div>
> ```

Add your link at the bottom, making the template file something like

> ```
> <div class="profile"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
>     <?php print render($user_profile); ?>
>     <?php if (in_array('my_role', $user->roles)): ?>
>        <p><a href="http://www.example.com">My link</a></p>    
>     <?php endif; ?>
>    </div>
> ```

- Make sure you clear your caches, visit a user account page, and make sure it's all working.
- Adjust the HTML above as you see fit...

Comment: Thanks!
I placed your code in my user-profile-edit.tpl.php as i needed the link on the user/edit pages. It works well. 

As the link is now not a field is it still possible to set a view permission on it?

Comment: Ooops, sorry that I missed that part.  Check out my updated code.  There's now a php if statement checking for a certain role that the permissions would be associated with.  This could be your own custom role or simply "authenticated user".  Hope it works!

Comment: I'm so glad! By the way, if any of your questions on the site are answered, one good practice is to hit the 'check mark' next to the answer that worked/was complete (to accept it).  I'm not implying you need to do that with my answer, of course, but am only saying this as an introduction into this site, since I know you're just getting started here.  Anyway, thanks for reporting back!